# BSOD 0x9A 1st param=3 SYSTEM_LICENSE_VIOLATION Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bsod

Solved the problem so this isn't a question but info for those who might care...

A post elsewhere from a clearly informed person noted that this error does not mean the license is invalid, but specifically that windows could not read one or both registry keys at HKLM/SYSTEM/SETUP/SetupType and .../SystemSetupInProgress

Booting from a PE CD, I could load the registry component from the system drive and clearly could read both values, and both were 0 as expected, so I spent some time following other suggestions.

Ultimately I simply changed both values to 1 and saved the edits, then loaded the hive again and set them back to zero. Problem solved. Basking.

Environment was an Intel-based RAID 10 system, fwiw.

Comment: To answer a question, write out the question first, then post the answer in the appropriate section. In a few days you'll be able to mark that as the correct answer. This way people will be able to tell this question has been answered and will be able to benefit from what you've learned.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author has indicated this isn’t a question.